# Second order homogeneous ODE with Jacobi elliptic coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

I am stuck looking for a solution for the 2nd order ODE

$$ x''(t) + \omega (t) x(t) =0$$

with $ \omega(t)=-1+3(1-e) \, nd \left( \sqrt{\frac{1+e}{2}} t, \ \frac{2e}{1+e} \right)^2$, where $nd$ is the Jacobi elliptic function and $0 \leq e \leq 1$.

I have tried an exponential ansatz

$$ x(t)=\mathrm{e}^{\int_0^t  \mathrm{d}t' f(t') } \; ,$$

but this only leads me to a first order inhomogeneous ODE

$$ f(t)^2+f'(t)=-\omega(t) \; .$$

I have solved it numerically, but I know this has an analytical solution (it's been done, but not explicitly given in a paper) which I don't know how to find.

I have also checked identities for squares and second derivatives of Jacobi elliptic functions, but no luck.

Does someone have any specific tricks or pointers?